# How to grant custom non-runtime permissions?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-permissions

In the launcher app we have custom "normal" permissions that are used for content provider:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.yandex.permissions.launcher.READ_BADGE_SETTINGS"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal"
    android:label="@string/permlab_read_badge_settings"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_read_badge_settings"/>

<permission
    android:name="com.yandex.permissions.launcher.WRITE_BADGE_SETTINGS"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal"
    android:label="@string/permlab_write_badge_settings"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_write_badge_settings"/>
```

The provider itself:

```
<provider
        android:name="${applicationId}.badges.BadgeContentProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.badges;${applicationId}.badges_external"
        android:readPermission="com.yandex.permissions.launcher.READ_BADGE_SETTINGS"
        android:writePermission="com.yandex.permissions.launcher.WRITE_BADGE_SETTINGS"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </provider>
```

There's an app that has declared to use these permissions in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.yandex.permissions.launcher.READ_BADGE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.yandex.permissions.launcher.WRITE_BADGE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Whenever the app is installed after the launcher, there are no issues with accessing content provider.

The issue shows when the app is installed before the launcher. After Launcher's installation and attempt to access the provider, there is `SecurityException` (doesn't matter which method I am trying to use: `query`, `insert`, `update`, `delete` and even `call`)

Trying to grant permissions via `grantUriPermission` does not help at all.

Is there any way to request "normal" level permissions at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

You're facing a "chicken and egg" type of problem.  If the launcher defines the permission and it is not installed first, then the system does not know about the permission at all.  In this case when the app which uses the permission is installed, the system just ignores the permissions because they don't exist.

If you think about it, this makes sense.  Otherwise, a malicious app could get installed before your launcher and define custom permissions exactly as your launcher does, effectively faking the permission for the app.

Normal permissions are automatically granted, if defined in the system and present in a `<uses-permissions>` tag in an app manifest.  There's no runtime request API necessary.

Answer (score 0):

"normal" level permissions are granted by the OS at installation time and there is no way we can use the permission model to request the permission at run time. However you can do following in the `onCreate()` of Launcher

```
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content:<your-content URI>");
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(NOTE_ACTION_VIEW); // SET CUSTOM INTENT ACTION
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); 
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivity(intent);
```

This will grant the permissions through Intent. Just one thing needs to check: What if `app` is not installed and you only installed `launcher`.

If this approach doesn't work then a workaround solution would be to make sure that the custom permissions have both a permission group, and a protection level of 'dangerous'. If these requirements are met, the system will provide a run time permission request support.